# Android, проблема при очистке поля по клику по нему

Tags: android

Есть поле ввода. Оно очищается, как только туда делаю фокус - начинаю вводить текст. Кликаю по полю, оно очищается и появляется клавиатура. 
Ввожу, кликаю по следующему элементу - все нормально.
НО! Если я снова кликну на поле оно очистится, или на клавиатуру есть такая  кнопка энтер или ок. По ней нажму тоже очистится поле...
Как сделать чтобы оно очищалось только при первом клике?
Хотя я придумал как, надо сделать событие при потере фокуса эдита и записать в переменную значение что очистка возможна, и при клике на поле если очистка `= true`,то очищать.

```
etSum.setOnClickListener(this);
....

case R.id.etSum:      // если клик по полю - чистим!
  etSum.setText("");
  Log.d(TAG, "клик по полю - чистка");
```

Так что вопрос, как сделать событые при потере фокуса (завершении ввода)...
или чтобы поле очищалось только при одном клике по полю...

Comment: Чтобы очищать поле **только** при первом клике, заведите некоторый флаг, который будет показывать, первый этот клик или нет, если первый  – очищайте (собственно, как Вы и написали). Другое дело, что в большинстве случаев, при первом клике на поле – оно пустое...

Comment: А зачем вам нужно такое странное поведение? Не лучше ли использовать подсказку (android:hint) вместо текста?

Comment: нужно именно такое - чтобы вводить постоянно разные цифры (т.к. программа - калькулятор) много раз расчитываются разные курсы.

Comment: @s8am да! именно! но как этот флаг снимать? я хотел его снимать, когда поле покинет фокус. а как отловить событие что завершен ввод и клава закрыта

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг, А зачем Вам его снимать? Вам нужно его только установить. Изначально флаг снят. При клике на поле ввода, проверяете, установлен ли флаг: если не установлен, то очищаете поле ввода и ставите флаг. Все. (правда смысла этого всего я так и не понял).